# Parallel BGL - Dijkstra shortest paths

Tags: c++, boost, graph, parallel-processing, mpi

I am currently trying to run a parallel Dijkstra shortest paths algorithm with the Parallel Boost Graph Library.
It is explained in detail, how it should be done, on this page: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/dijkstra_example.html

However the first Problem I've encountered is, that my windows HPC MPI and boost 1.63 could not recognize the following line:

> typedef mpi::process_group <*mpi::immediateS*> process_group_type;

I've found out that one could use the **boost::graph::distributed::mpi_process_group** in this case.

My code looks like this, and as explained is almost identical to the tutorial, beside the one line:

```
using namespace boost;
using boost::graph::distributed::mpi_process_group;



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    boost::mpi::environment env(argc, argv);

    typedef adjacency_list < listS, distributedS<mpi_process_group, vecS>,
        directedS,
        no_property,                 // Vertex properties
        property<edge_weight_t, int> // Edge properties
    > graph_t;
    typedef graph_traits < graph_t >::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor;
    typedef graph_traits < graph_t >::edge_descriptor edge_descriptor;

    typedef std::pair<int, int> Edge;
    const int num_nodes = 5;
    enum nodes { A, B, C, D, E };
    char name[] = "ABCDE";
    Edge edge_array[] = { Edge(A, C), Edge(B, B), Edge(B, D), Edge(B, E),
        Edge(C, B), Edge(C, D), Edge(D, E), Edge(E, A), Edge(E, B)
    };
    int weights[] = { 1, 2, 1, 2, 7, 3, 1, 1, 1 };
    int num_arcs = sizeof(edge_array) / sizeof(Edge);

    graph_t g(edge_array, edge_array + num_arcs, weights, num_nodes);
    // Keeps track of the predecessor of each vertex
    std::vector<vertex_descriptor> p(num_vertices(g));
    // Keeps track of the distance to each vertex
    std::vector<int> d(num_vertices(g));

    vertex_descriptor s = vertex(A, g);
    dijkstra_shortest_paths
        (g, s,
            predecessor_map(
                make_iterator_property_map(p.begin(), get(vertex_index, g))).
            distance_map(
                make_iterator_property_map(d.begin(), get(vertex_index, g)))
            );


    std::cout << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Nonetheless I still have an error:

> ..boost_1_63_0\boost\graph\distributed\dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp(116): error C2664: 'void boost::local_put,boost::default_color_type>(boost::dummy_property_map,const Key &,const Value &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'boost::iterator_property_map>>,IndexMap,boost::default_color_type,boost::default_color_type &>' to 'boost::dummy_property_map'

I've searched through many sites and I am considering right now to try another boost version or another mpi. Does the tutorial work as explained in the link,and does my code work, or did I do something completely wrong?

Thank you very much!

---

***Addendum*: Problem was solved**

Solution to this problem were basically two things:

- First of all, to check the includes, I included the boost directories in a wrong order, begin with serialization and continue...
- The second factor are the libraries and the os. Boost Graph library in general seems to work much smoother on unix systems.

Comment: Sequential version? What is that?

Comment: The non -parallel version. Basically just replace distributedS<mpi_process_group, vecS> with vecS, as explained in the tutorial I linked above

Comment: I am currently trying boost 1.65.1 and I will update the status... I am running out of options since I do not know the slightest what is causing the problem.

Comment: Tried it, nothing changed, same error.

Comment: Lol. I'm unable to compile & link this on my Ubuntu box. I must be incompetent (recompiled all of boost with the mpi/graph_parallel bits enabled)

Comment: Thank you, that is interesting, I did not mention that my error is also a compile error. Did you get the same error I have?

Comment: Nope. I get linker errors. Using bjam links, but doesn't run

Comment: oh, I am clueless, is the code causing it? I linked it to the stage\lib folder in boost, however it is windows

Comment: Of course not. Like I said, the Jamfile.v2 does build the sample. Output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25497630/ (so I tried to recreate the sample with my own makefiles as I usually do, but fail)

Comment: I see sorry, thank you. Did you use a metis input file? Would you recommend it over a graph defined in the way I did it above. This would be my next step, using a metis input, maybe it will fix the error.

Comment: Mmm. Yeah, using the `graph/test/weighted_graph.gr` file it did work, resulting in http://i.imgur.com/JHPYIXw.png

Comment: Impressive.Would you mind sharing the metis part of the code? I tried it like in graph_parallel/example/dijkstra_shortest_paths.cpp and it did not work for me with metis.

Comment: @sehe Ok, I've tried different things, and the Depth-First Visit works, however the Dijkstra_shortest_path still gives me an error, but another one: 
 `c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility(1005): error C2338: next requires forward iterator` I couldn't find anything about this error

Comment: and this also seems a bit suspicious `>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility(288): warning C4503: '__LINE__Var': decorated name length exceeded, name was truncated`

Comment: Those warnings are generally benign.

Comment: Ok, I tried it on ubuntu and it works! A solution to this problem on windows would still be great.

Comment: Please do not add any SOLVED into the question title. You can write an answer and accept it, if you want.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, good to  know! I actually did not do it, it was  the editor before you.

Comment: `fatal error: ' boost / graph / distributed / two_bit_color_map.hpp ' file not found`

I ran into this problem when using this code with boost 1.74 with ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. How did you solve this?

Comment: https://paste-bin.xyz/39439 This is the full code with all include needed